# Python: os.path.exists failing on "~/foo"

Tags: python, ubuntu, directory, os.path

I'm attempting check if a directory exists by running

```
self.path = '~/foo'
    if not os.path.exists(self.path):
        os.makedirs(self.path)
```

On an Ubuntu virtual machine. Although this directory does not exist, it does not make the directory. In fact using a print statement right above the makedirs command. Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to `os.path.expanduser` on the path first...